# How can the function's composite be convex function?

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis

$h$ is a continuous function which is convex and strictly decreasing;
$t$ is a continuous function which is strictly increasing;
$\operatorname{ran}(t)$ is included in $\operatorname{dom}(h)$.
Under what conditions can the composite $h\circ t$ be a convex function?

Answer (score 0):

The composition is convex whenever $t$ is concave; the assumption that $t$ is increasing can be dropped. Proof: write $h$ as an upper envelope of decreasing affine functions $\phi_\alpha$ and note that each $\phi_\alpha\circ t$ is convex; the supremum of convex functions is convex. Incidentally, this contributes an item for  [When does it help to write a function as $f(x) = \sup_\alpha \phi_{\alpha}(x)$ (an upper envelope)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/575312)

Without additional restrictions on $h$, the concavity of $t$ is also necessary. Indeed, $h$ could be $h(x)=-x$, in which case the convexity  of $h\circ t$ is precisely the concavity of $t$.